# How to set application version on the Sentry error capturing?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-sentry

Recently, I installed **Sentry** on my React Native application. I set my initializing configuration like below:

```js
import { SentryToken } from './app/helpers/config';
import { environment } from './app/helpers/env';

Sentry.init({
  dsn: SentryToken,
  environment,
});
```

And on the issue dashboard, I can see all errors, messages and etc.

But in one of the message report I saw the Sentry reports whole the device, OS and especially the application:

[image: App Version]

Actually, I wanna know *where does the **version** come from?*

I even pass the `version` key but still, it doesn't make any difference the `version in the Sentry dashboard is still on` 1.0`.

I read whole the [documentation about options](https://docs.sentry.io/sdks/javascript/config/basics/) but there is nothing to help me.

*where does the **version** come from?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I find out sentry brings the `Version` and the `Build` number from Xcode:

[image: Xcode]

Actually, these two numbers come from the `info.plist` file and `project.pbxproj` file with the following file:

- `info.plist`: ios/[projectName]/Info.plist
- `project.pbxproj`: ios/[projectName].xcodeproj/project.pbxproj